# Unable to register ec2 instances with ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

**Error:**

`service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container Instances were found in your cluster`

I see the list of resources are properly created:

`VPC, subnets, route tables, internet gateways, NatGW, EC2 instance, security groups, load balancer.`

Ec2 instance is up and running but still the deployment is stuck in progress and times out with rollback state.

I added the signaling script as well:
`/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup --region ${AWS::Region}`

Don't know what else is missing.

**Cloud formation template:**

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  VPCEnv:
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1
    Description: 'The id for references to test Services created items.'

  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Environment to create backend infra for'

  KeyName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the ECS instances.'

  DesiredCapacity:
    Type: String
    Default: '1'
    Description: 'Number of instances to launch in your ECS cluster.'

  MaxSize:
    Type: String
    Default: '1'
    Description: Maximum number of instances that can be launched in your ECS cluster.

  InstanceType:
    Description: 'EC2 instance type'
    Type: String
    Default: 't2.medium'

  BackendContainerImage:
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1

  Version:
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1

  AMIID:
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1

Resources:
  ExecutionRole:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: 'Allow'
                Principal:
                  Service: ['ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com']
                Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: !Sub test-${Environment}-execution-user-role
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                  - Effect: 'Allow'
                    Action: ['ecs:CreateCluster', 'ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance', 'ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint',
                            'ecs:Poll', 'ecs:RegisterContainerInstance', 'ecs:StartTelemetrySession',
                            'ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState', 'ecs:Submit*', 'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken',
                            'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability', 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer', 'ecr:BatchGetImage',
                            'logs:CreateLogStream', 'logs:PutLogEvents', 'ssm:GetParameter', 'kms:Decrypt', 'ssm:GetParameters']
                    Resource: '*'

  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster

  EcsSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: ECS Security Group
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VPCEnv}-VPC"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        -
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          SourceSecurityGroupId:
            Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VPCEnv}-BastionSecurityGroup"
        -
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '31000'
          ToPort: '61000'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup

  LoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Sub "test-${Environment}-LBSecurityGroup"
      GroupDescription:  test service Load Balancer Security Group
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VPCEnv}-VPC"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        -
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          SourceSecurityGroupId:
            Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VPCEnv}-APILoadBalancerSecurityGroup"

  testServiceTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: !Sub 'test-${Environment}'
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: !Sub 'test-${Environment}-container'
        Cpu: 600
        Essential: 'true'
        Image: !Ref BackendContainerImage
        Memory: 1800
        PortMappings:
          - ContainerPort: 3000

  ECSALBDNS:
    Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSet"
    Properties:
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !GetAtt [ ECSALB, DNSName ]
        HostedZoneId: !GetAtt [ ECSALB, CanonicalHostedZoneID ]
      Comment: Internal DNS entry for audit service load balancer.
      HostedZoneId: Z03303053NOQR6YO05FA7
      Name: !Sub "api.internal.audit.service.${Environment}.altusplatform.com."
      Type: A

  ECSALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "test-${Environment}-lb"
      Scheme: internal
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
      - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
        Value: '20'
      Subnets:
        Fn::Split:
          - ','
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VPCEnv}-PrivateSubnets2"
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
        - Fn::ImportValue : !Sub "${VPCEnv}-APILoadBalancerSecurityGroup"

  ALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn: ECSServiceRole
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'ECSTG'
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref 'ECSALB'
      Port: '80'
      Protocol: HTTP

  ECSALBListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    DependsOn: ALBListener
    Properties:
      Actions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'ECSTG'
      Conditions:
      - Field: path-pattern
        Values: [/]
      ListenerArn: !Ref 'ALBListener'
      Priority: 1

  ECSTG:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    DependsOn: ECSALB
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPath: /health
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Name: !Sub "test-${Environment}-tg"
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VPCEnv}-VPC"

  ECSCapacityProvider:
    Type: AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider
    Properties:
        AutoScalingGroupProvider:
            AutoScalingGroupArn: !Ref 'ECSAutoScalingGroup'
            ManagedScaling:
                MaximumScalingStepSize: 10
                MinimumScalingStepSize: 1
                Status: ENABLED
                TargetCapacity: 100
        Tags:
            - Key: environment
              Value: !Sub '${Environment}'

  ECSAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        Fn::Split:
          - ','
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VPCEnv}-PrivateSubnets2"
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref 'ContainerInstances'
      MinSize: '1'
      MaxSize: !Ref 'MaxSize'
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref 'DesiredCapacity'

  ContainerInstances:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Sub '${AMIID}'
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup']
      InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref 'EC2InstanceProfile'
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          yum update -y
          echo ECS_CLUSTER=${ECSCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
          yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
          yum install -y awslogs jq
          region=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .region)
          sed -i -e "s/region = us-east-1/region = $region/g" /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf
          yum install -y https://amazon-ssm-$region.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm

  service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: ALBListener
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref 'ECSCluster'
      DesiredCount: '2'
      LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: !Sub 'test-${Environment}-container'
        ContainerPort: 3000
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'ECSTG'
      Role: !Ref 'ECSServiceRole'
      TaskDefinition: !Ref 'testServiceTaskDefinition'
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 150
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 50

  ECSServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ecs.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ['elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer', 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets',
              'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*', 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer',
              'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets', 'ec2:Describe*', 'ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress']
            Resource: '*'

  ServiceScalingTarget:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    DependsOn: service
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 1
      MinCapacity: 1
      ResourceId: !Join ['', [service/, !Ref 'ECSCluster', /, !GetAtt [service, Name]]]
      RoleARN: !GetAtt [AutoscalingRole, Arn]
      ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
      ServiceNamespace: ecs

  ServiceScalingPolicy:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: AStepPolicy
      PolicyType: StepScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref 'ServiceScalingTarget'
      StepScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        AdjustmentType: PercentChangeInCapacity
        Cooldown: 60
        MetricAggregationType: Average
        StepAdjustments:
        - MetricIntervalLowerBound: 0
          ScalingAdjustment: 200

  EC2Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ec2.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ['ecs:CreateCluster', 'ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance', 'ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint',
              'ecs:Poll', 'ecs:RegisterContainerInstance', 'ecs:StartTelemetrySession', 'ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState',
              'ecs:Submit*', 'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken', 'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability', 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer', 'ecr:BatchGetImage',
              'logs:CreateLogStream', 'logs:PutLogEvents']
            Resource: '*'

  AutoscalingRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: service-autoscaling
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ['application-autoscaling:*', 'cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms', 'cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm',
              'ecs:DescribeServices', 'ecs:UpdateService']
            Resource: '*'

  EC2InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles: [!Ref 'EC2Role']

Outputs:
  ecsservice:
    Value: !Ref 'service'
  ecscluster:
    Value: !Ref 'ECSCluster'
  ECSALB:
    Description: Your ALB DNS URL
    Value: !Join ['', [!GetAtt [ECSALB, DNSName]]]
  taskdef:
    Value: !Ref 'testServiceTaskDefinition'
```

Exported values:

[image]

**Update:**  Added the `ECSCapacityProvider` with no luck

Comment: You are using lots of import values, while the template that exports them is not shown.

Comment: @Marcin Updated the question with exported values

Comment: Your VPC may be incorrect. You haven't provided any info about your VPC, route tables, subnets.

Comment: @Marcin VPC is `atlantis-VPC` which is last exported value in sheet and I am importing it as `Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VPCEnv}-VPC"`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the above issue when configuring autoscaling with an ECS Cluster.  In order for autoscaling to correctly report the instances it creates back to the ECS Cluster an autoscaling group capacity provider needs to be created:

```
Type: AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider
Properties: 
  AutoScalingGroupProvider: 
    AutoScalingGroupProvider
  Name: String
  Tags: 
    - Tag
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/asg-capacity-providers.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-capacityprovider.html

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: @kittu, totally guessing here, but based off the information here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-container-instance-requirement-error/ perhaps extend your TaskDefinition/PortMappings to also include HostPort: 0 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-portmappings.html).  This should enable dynamic port mapping between the host instance and the container. (Assuming leaving it out doesn't set a default of 0)